# Implement tqdm progress bar into copy_from() method in Psycopg2

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, progress-bar, psycopg2, tqdm

I am using the following example from [this blog article](https://naysan.ca/2020/05/09/pandas-to-postgresql-using-psycopg2-bulk-insert-performance-benchmark/) for inserting a large pandas dataframes into a PostgreSQL tables:

```
import os
import pandas as pd
import psycopg2
from io import StringIO

def copy_from_stringio(conn, df, table):
    """
    Here we are going save the dataframe in memory and use copy_from() to copy it to the table
    """
    # save dataframe to an in memory buffer
    buffer = StringIO()
    df.to_csv(buffer, index_label='id', header=False)
    buffer.seek(0)
    
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    try:
        cursor.copy_from(buffer, table, sep=",")
        conn.commit()
    except (Exception, psycopg2.DatabaseError) as error:
        print("Error: %s" % error)
        conn.rollback()
        cursor.close()
        return 1
    print("copy_from_stringio() done")
    cursor.close()
```

My question is how to implement TQDM progress bar into this function so I could see uploading progress?

Thanks!